# flash drag and drop one of many sprite instances

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have problem with drag and drop function and object selection.

I create simple flash arranger (add table icon to stage - room). I have button which create new instance of table icon, wchich i can drag and drop over the stage.

Problem is that i can drag and drop only last added icon. If i add new instance od icon i can not take (drag and drop) any icon created before :/

my code here: main class

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.Event;
import com.adobe.images.JPGEncoder;
import flash.geom.Point;

btn_middleTable.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, f_middleIco);
btn_bigTable.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, f_bigIco);
btnSave.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, f_save);

function f_middleIco(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var middle:MiddleIco = new MiddleIco();
    middle.x = 20;
    middle.y = 20;
    stage.addChild(middle);
    trace("created");
}

function f_bigIco(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var big:BigIco = new BigIco();
    big.x = 20;
    big.y = 20;
    stage.addChild(big);
    trace("created");
}

function f_save(event:MouseEvent)
{
    var jpgEncoder:JPGEncoder;
    jpgEncoder = new JPGEncoder(90);

    var bitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(stage.width, stage.height);
    bitmapData.draw(stage, new Matrix());
    var img = jpgEncoder.encode(bitmapData);

    var file:FileReference = new FileReference();
    file.save(img, "filename.png");
}
```

icon instance package:

```
package  {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.geom.Point;

    public class BigIco extends MovieClip {
            public var active:Boolean;

        public function BigIco() {
            // constructor code
            this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, f_move);
            this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,downf);
            this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,upf);
        }

        public function f_move(e:Event)
        {
            if(active==true)
            {
                startDrag();
            }
            else if(active==false)
            {
                stopDrag();
            }
        }

        public function downf(e:MouseEvent)
        {
            active = true;
        }
        public function upf(e:MouseEvent)
        {
            active = false;
        }
}
}
```

what can i do to have ability to select every icon (instance) which is actually over mouse cursor?

Comment: Note that while my answer completely removes `f_move`, in that method, there's no need for `else if(active==false)` - if `active` is not true, it's false, so `else` would be enough. You can also shorten `if(active==true)` to `if (active)`.

Comment: One last thing: Except for rather advanced cases, it's not a good idea to use `stage.addChild()` to add instances to the main timeline - because you're not actually adding them to the timeline, but "next to it" in the display hierarchy (the main timeline that you see in Flash is, itself, a child of `stage`). It works here, but in other cases it may result in hard to find bugs, and what you actually want here is `this.addChild()`. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13096993/correct-use-of-addchild

Answer (score 0):

Theory: `startDrag` and `stopDrag` aren't meant to be called repeatedly - but they will be, once every frame, for every clip you add, because you're using an `ENTER_FRAME` listener.

I haven't tested this, but calling `stopDrag` may actually stop *any* dragging - including on other clips - because you're [only allowed to drag a single `Sprite` (and hence `MovieClip`) in the first place](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Sprite.html#startDrag%28%29).

So, if that theory holds, `startDrag()` on your first icon will be cancelled immediately by `f_move()` on the new icon calling `stopDrag()`.

But there's no need for you the `ENTER_FRAME` listener in any event. This should give the same result (except it actually works) - simply calling the drag methods immediately in the mouse listeners:

```
public class BigIco extends MovieClip {
    public var active:Boolean;

    public function BigIco() {
        // constructor code
        this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, downf);
        this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, upf);
    }

    public function downf(e:MouseEvent)
    {
        // Unless you're going to use 'active' for other stuff,
        // you can remove this line:
        active = true; 
        startDrag();
    }
    public function upf(e:MouseEvent)
    {
        // Same here:
        active = false;
        stopDrag();
    }
}
```

Other than that, I can't spot any real problems in your code.

**EDIT: "Perfect" version, also detecting mouse up if pointer isn't over icon:**

```
public class BigIco extends MovieClip {

    public function BigIco() {
        // Only add mouse down listener here. We'll add up when needed below:
        this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,downf);
    }

    public function downf(e:MouseEvent)
    {
        // Add event listener to stage, so as to be triggered even if
        // the pointer isn't over the icon when releasing the button.
        // Note that this will also work even with the mouse *outside*
        // the stage/swf area:
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,upf);
        startDrag();
    }
    public function upf(e:MouseEvent)
    {
        // Remember to remove the event listener after use:
        stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, upf);
        stopDrag();
    }
}
```

Comment: if I leave only mous down and mouse up event i can't drop my icon ;/
`package  {
 
 import flash.display.MovieClip;
 import flash.events.MouseEvent;
 import flash.events.Event;
 import flash.geom.Point;
 
 public class BigIco extends MovieClip {
   public var active:Boolean;
  
  public function BigIco() {

   this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,downf);
   this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,upf);
  }

  
  public function downf(e:MouseEvent)
  {
    startDrag();
  }
  public function upf(e:MouseEvent)
  {
   stopDrag();
   
  }
  
  
 }
 
}`

Comment: Works fine for me - and has in around 20-30 earlier projects. But if you release the mouse button when the cursor isn't actually over the clip, it won't be notified. For that, you'll need to handle MOUSE_UP on the stage instead - so that it gets triggered no matter where the mouse cursor is.

Comment: Will try do something with that, thanks. If i will have trouble i will write. thanks for help :).

Comment: And just for demonstration's sake, here's the exact same file, with your original timeline code, and the code I listed above: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14034871/StackOverflow/patio2.zip (temporary link, will remove it and this comment when seen). Works exactly the same - without spaghetti code. ;-)

Comment: Thanks, i will look at it. I make spaghetti code because I dont know any programing la nguage well :/ I know only basic things :). Thanks again

Comment: Don't worry about the spaghetti - it's just a way to describe code that is tangled, not really a criticism - especially not when it comes to Flash, where a lot of bugs and quirks sometimes *force* us to do some messy stuff. In this case, however, I don't think it's needed.